# rsync error using ssh from Python script run as sudo

Tags: ssh, python, rsync

Under Debian Linux on a Raspberry Pi, I am trying to run rsync from within a Python script using an ssh key so that I don't have to supply a password.  I'm planning to run the Python script as a service.  From within the script myScript.py, I use

```
def syncImageFiles(remoteUser, src, dest):
   runssh = f"'ssh -i /home/{remoteUser}/.ssh/id_rsa'"
   syncCmd = ['rsync', '-zr', '--bwlimit=400', '--delete', '-e', runssh, src, dest]
   subprocess.run(syncCmd)
   ...

syncImageFiles('pi', 'pi@192.168.1.80:/home/pi/images/', '/home/user1/images')
```

When I run the script logged in as user1 on the local Raspberry Pi as follows

```
sudo python3 myScript.py
```

I get the following error

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory (2)
```

However, if I run the rsync command as sudo on the command line as follows

```
sudo rsync -zr --bwlimit=400 --delete -e 'ssh -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa' pi@192.168.1.80:/home/pi/images/ '/home/user1/images'
```

It works just fine.  I have tried supplying the full path /usr/bin/ssh to no effect.  Adding

```
fullCmd = ' '.join(syncCmd)
logging.info(fullCmd)
```

I have verified that the result looks exactly like what I am entering on the command line, minus "sudo".  So what am I missing?

UPDATE: I have gleaned some clues from additional web searches.  It seems that the reason that I am getting the file not found error is that rsync is treating the entire string passed to the -e option as a file.  I think I need a way to force the -e option to see individual arguments, similar to the way I am using syncCmd to present individual arguments to subprocess.run().  If my guess is correct, perhaps this is better posted in a Python forum for answers.

Comment: Why have you doubly quoted the value for `runssh`? I'm not particularly familiar with python but I would have expected `runssh = f"ssh -i /home/{remoteUser}/.ssh/id_rsa"`

Comment: "_I need a way to force the -e option to see individual arguments_" the more I look at your code the more I'm sure that the issue is because you've doubly-quoted the value for `runssh`

Comment: If you don't embed the single quotes inside the double-quoted expression, then the executed command would be `rsync -zr --bwlimit=400 --delete -e ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa pi@192.168.1.80:/home/pi/images/ '/home/user1/images'`.  The double quotes preserve the single quotes required for the command.

Comment: I just discovered a workaround solution here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770209/run-child-processes-as-different-user-from-a-long-running-python-process/6037494#6037494).  It avoids having to supply the -e option entirely by providing a pre-execution function to the subprocess which changes the user from root to a different user before running the command, so the default ssh identifier is used.

Comment: I just made a correction to the original post.  `/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa` should have been `/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa`.  That's what my script has been using all along, I just transcribed it incorrectly.  The issue with the -e option is unaffected by that.

Comment: The single quotes should not be part of the argument to the `-e` option. It would be like saying `rsync ... -e "'ssh -i file'" ...`.  The array elements defines the individual arguments, not your quoting.

Comment: The expression `f"'ssh -i file'"` in Python does not preserve the double quotes.  In Python, the double quotes are simply a way of telling Python "everything inside is a character in a string".  For example, `print(f"'I am a string'")` produces the output `'I am a string'`, not `"'I am a string'"`.  So the value of the runssh passed to rsync in the code above does not include double quotes.

Comment: Step back.. From here, it looks like you are trying to do ten giant steps in a single line of code, instead of only 15 small steps to reach your end goal. Lay it all out on paper--well, notepad or a ext editor, so you can insert lines later--and then see if you can break each step down in to smaller steps. If my guess is correct, you might find that the issues like quoting are the result of trying to do too much at once: a huge giant step that is five times as costly as a small step, when you only need two or three less costly small steps...